# Getting 'objects are not a valid React child' error when attempting to render date in React web app

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to pull a string integer from my database, convert it into a number, then transform that number into a date.

However, I keep getting the following error every time I load my page when live.

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Mon Dec 14 2020
> 10:48:11 GMT+0000 (GMT)). If you meant to render a collection of
> children, use an array instead.

The date variables are working exactly as expected, I just want to now render them in my app, which is where the problem is occurring.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong here?

Here's my full component....

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './individual-debts.css';
import IndividualDebtCard from '../individual-debts/individual-debt-card';


    class IndividualDebts extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
          debts: []
        }
    
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
    
        axios.get("/api/fetch/fetchDebtCards")
        .then((response) => {
          this.setState({
            debts: response.data,
            fetchInProgress: false
          })
        })
        })
    
    
      }
    
      render() {
    
        const fetchDebts = this.state.debts.map (debt => {
    
          const dayCurrent = new Date();
          const dayFromDB = parseInt(debt.date);
          const dayFromDBDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(dayFromDB));
          const variableDayFromDB = new Date(new Date().setDate(dayFromDB));
          const dayFromDBDatePlusOne = variableDayFromDB.setMonth(variableDayFromDB.getMonth()+1)
          let dayToRender = ''
    
          if (dayCurrent < dayFromDBDate) {
               dayToRender = dayFromDBDate
               console.log(dayToRender)
          } else {
              dayToRender = variableDayFromDB
              console.log(dayToRender)
          }
    
          return (
    
           <IndividualDebtCard key={debt._id}
            monthly={debt.monthly}
            repayment={dayToRender} />
    
                )
            })
    
        return (
          <div>
           {fetchDebts}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    
    export default IndividualDebts;
```

Any advice here would be really appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: the error is coming from the card, you should put its code in the question. But if you just display the prop, it can't as dates are objects.

Answer (score 1):

**Date** instance is an *object* in JavaScript so it cant be passed as a **children** prop in react (since it accepts only a string or an element)

To solve this issue simply convert the Date instance to an **ISOString** (or any other format you like)

```
 <IndividualDebtCard
   key={debt._id}
   monthly={debt.monthly}
   repayment={dayToRender.toISOString()} />
```

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty much spot on - toLocaleString is what I needed exactly, but this led me on the right path.

Comment: @JonNicholson Glad I could help, also make sure to mark this answer as accepted if it helped you (should be able to see a tick mark under the points)

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to render your date in a `<p>` (for example), it won't work as dates are Objects.

You could write a function to transform it to a string or use a lib like `date-fns`.

Here is a go at it:

```html
export const DisplayDate = (date: Date | string | number): string => {
    if (date) {
        const dateAsDate = new Date(date);
        const day =
            dateAsDate.getDate() < 10
                ? `0${dateAsDate.getDate()}`
                : dateAsDate.getDate();
        const month =
            dateAsDate.getMonth() < 9
                ? `0${dateAsDate.getMonth() + 1}`
                : `${dateAsDate.getMonth() + 1}`;
        const year = dateAsDate.getFullYear();
        return `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
    }
    return '-';
};
```